# mysql_fetch_array is returning blank array, but correct number of rows

Tags: php, mysql

I am using a while loop to parse through my database, and I know that the information is there.  It is a forum style setup, and after I add a topic and return to the main page, the new line is added, but still blank.  I will include my code, I'm not quite sure what I am missing that would cause it to not bring the data from the DB.  Also, I am not using PHPMyAdmin, and I believe this tutorial code was originally written for use with it, if this helps address the difference in syntax I might need to solve the problem. Thanks in advance.

```
mysql_connect("$host","$username","$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name ORDER BY id DESC;";
//order result by descending

$result=mysql_query($sql);
?>

<table width="90%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1"  bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>
<td width="6%" align="center" bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><strong>#</strong></td>
<td width="53%" align="center" bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><strong>Topic</strong></td>
<td width="15%" align="center" bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><strong>Views</strong></td>
<td width="13%" align="center" bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><strong>Replies</strong></td>
<td width="13%" align="center" bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><strong>Date/Time</strong></td>
</tr>

<?php

//start looping table row
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo $rows['id'];?></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><a href="view_topic.php?id=<? echo $rows['id'];?>"><?echo $rows['topic']; ?>
</a><BR></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo $rows['view']; ?></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo $rows['reply']; ?></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo $rows['datetime']; ?></td>
</tr>

<?php
// Exit looping and close connection

}
mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: first of all, dont use mysql functions, since they are officially deprecated, look into PDO or Prepared statements, second: var_dump($rows); and you'll solve your question in no time.

Comment: remove `;` in end of query

Comment: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. It's awful and is being removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices. Always be absolutely **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will have severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: syntex error , you are adding 2 semicolans ** id DESC;";** change it to **id DESC";**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test this : replace `<?` by <`?php`

So `<? echo $rows['view']; ?>` by `<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>` idem view, reply, datetime